# Get data from two columns in the database and add to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, arraylist

I do not know how to get the data of two columns. I only know how to do it when it deals with one column only.

here is the code where the issue is:

```
public ArrayList<String> getData() {

        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table where id = 1", null);

try {
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                      String levelData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column1"));

                List.add("" + levelData);

                    }
                      while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                Log.e("Retrieve Data", "Unable to get Data " + e);
        }

        return List;
    }
```

I know that the problem is at the `c.getColumnIndex("Column1"));` because that will be the place where to type the column of the table you want to get data from. But what will I do if I will try to do it using two columns?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple. it was the first time i tried this and i didn't expect it to work so
this is what i did:

```
try {
if (c != null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
                  String levelData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column1"));

            List.add("" + levelData);

                }
                  while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

    if (c != null) {
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
                  String levelData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column2"));

            List.add("" + levelData);

                }
                  while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            Log.e("Retrieve Data", "Unable to get Data " + e);
    }
```

I simply added another exact code but this time, it reads Column2 and worked as expected. :D

Answer (score 0):

Make a java bean class with 2 variable and their getters & Setters like

public class Data {

```
String coloumn1;
String coloumn2;

public String getColoumn1() {

    return coloumn1;

}
public void setColoumn1(String coloumn1) {

    this.coloumn1 = coloumn1;

}

public String getColoumn2() {

    return coloumn2;

}
public void setColoumn2(String coloumn2) {
    this.coloumn2 = coloumn2;
}
```

}

**Use**

ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();

dataList.setsetColoumn1(Your Data);

same for coloumn2 and for getters.